# Mocking a SignInManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

New to unit testing with Moq and xUnit. I am trying to mock a `SignInManager` that is used in a controller constructor to build a unit test. The documentation that I can find for the `SignInManager` constructor says it accepts a `UserManager` and `AuthenticationManager` object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt173769(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`2.

When I try to mock the controller, I get an error saying it was unable to instantiate a proxy of the `SignInManager` and `AuthenticationManager` classes.

Error:

> "Message:
>   Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can
>   not instantiate proxy of class:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager1[[Models.AppUser,
>   , Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]. Could not find a constructor that would match
>   given arguments: Castle.Proxies.UserManager`1Proxy
>   Castle.Proxies.AuthenticationManagerProxy"

The unit test:

```
public void Can_Send_Password_Reset_Email()
{
    //Arrange
    //create mock services
    Mock<IEmailService> mockEmailService = new Mock<IEmailService>();
    Mock<ILessonRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<ILessonRepository>();
    Mock<UserManager<AppUser>> mockUsrMgr = GetMockUserManager();
    var mockSignInMgr = GetMockSignInManager();
    Mock<UserValidator<AppUser>> mockUsrVal = new Mock<UserValidator<AppUser>>();
    Mock<PasswordValidator<AppUser>> mockPwdVal = new Mock<PasswordValidator<AppUser>>();
    Mock<PasswordHasher<AppUser>> mockPwdHshr = new Mock<PasswordHasher<AppUser>>();
    Mock<ForgotPasswordModel> model = new Mock<ForgotPasswordModel>();
    model.Object.Email = "joe@example.com";

    var user = new AppUser();
    var token = mockUsrMgr.Object.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user).Result;

    //create mock temporary data, needed for controller message
    Mock<ITempDataDictionary> tempData = new Mock<ITempDataDictionary>();
    //create the controller
    //ERROR ON THIS LINE
    AccountController controller = new AccountController(mockUsrMgr.Object, mockSignInMgr.Object, mockUsrVal.Object, mockPwdVal.Object, mockPwdHshr.Object, mockEmailService.Object)
    {
        TempData = tempData.Object
    };

    //Act
    //the controller should call the email action method
    controller.PasswordResetEmail(model.Object);

    //Assert
    //verify that the email service method was called one time
    mockEmailService.Verify(m => m.PasswordResetMessage(user, "Test Email"), Times.Once());
}
```

The SignInManager mocking function:

```
//create a mock SignInManager class
private Mock<SignInManager<AppUser>> GetMockSignInManager()
{
    var mockUsrMgr = GetMockUserManager();
    var mockAuthMgr = new Mock<AuthenticationManager>();
    return new Mock<SignInManager<AppUser>>(mockUsrMgr.Object, mockAuthMgr.Object);
}
```

The `GetMockUserManager()` works fine in other unit tests and doesn't appear to be the issue.

Answer (score 25):

This is how I do it, I hope this helps you.

```
public class FakeSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public FakeSignInManager()
            : base(new FakeUserManager(),
                 new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>().Object,
                 new Mock<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
                 new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
                 new Mock<ILogger<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>>().Object,
                 new Mock<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider>().Object)
        { }        
}



public class FakeUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public FakeUserManager()
            : base(new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
              new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
              new Mock<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
              new IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>[0],
              new IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>[0],
              new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
              new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
              new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
              new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>>().Object)
        { }

        public override Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
        }

        public override Task<IdentityResult> AddToRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string role)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
        }

        public override Task<string> GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: why creating a new class when you can simply create direct mocks in the test function.
Now you will have to test this class too!

Comment: Instead of doing `new Mock<X>().Object`, you can use `Mock.Of<X>()`.

Answer (score 11):

For ASP.NET Core 5, this setup can be used:

```
var userManagerMock = new Mock<UserManager<User>>(
    /* IUserStore<TUser> store */Mock.Of<IUserStore<User>>(),
    /* IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor */null,
    /* IPasswordHasher<TUser> passwordHasher */null,
    /* IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TUser>> userValidators */null,
    /* IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TUser>> passwordValidators */null,
    /* ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer */null,
    /* IdentityErrorDescriber errors */null,
    /* IServiceProvider services */null,
    /* ILogger<UserManager<TUser>> logger */null);

var signInManagerMock = new Mock<SignInManager<User>>(
    userManagerMock.Object,
    /* IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor */Mock.Of<IHttpContextAccessor>(),
    /* IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser> claimsFactory */Mock.Of<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>>(),
    /* IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor */null,
    /* ILogger<SignInManager<TUser>> logger */null,
    /* IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes */null,
    /* IUserConfirmation<TUser> confirmation */null);
```

Comment: Works on .net Core 6 as well. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

the `SignInManager` Has no Constructor with no argument so you have to pass the arguments in the `new Mock<SignInManager>(**Params here**)`

Some of these paramaters cannot not be null so they have to be mocked too like :

1. `UserManager<TUser>` ==> the First Argument.
2. `IHttpContextAccessor` ==> the second argument.

The probleme here is even `UserManager` have not a parameter less constructor so you have to mock with its parameters

For `Usermanager` the parameter that should not be null `IUserStore<User>` ==> the first parameter

so here how I did with minimum code

```
var _mockUserManager = new Mock<ApiUserManager>(new Mock<IUserStore<ApiUser>>().Object,
                null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
var _contextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
var _userPrincipalFactory = new Mock<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApiUser>>();
Mock<ApiSignInManager>mockApiSignInManager = new Mock<ApiSignInManager>(_mockUserManager.Object,
               _contextAccessor.Object, _userPrincipalFactory.Object, null, null, null);
```

this response were inspired by [umutesen on GitHub Forum](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/640#issuecomment-438602993)

Answer (score 3):

The documentation you are looking at is for [`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt173769.aspx).

If you look at the error message, you will see that Moq is actually trying to create an object of type `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`. Note the difference beetween `AspNet` and `AspNetCore`.

So basically, you were looking at the `SignInManager` that was used in the old Owin-based Identity stack for the classic ASP.NET. But you need to look at the ASP.NET Core version. If you look at the documentation of that type, you will see that the [constructor has a *few* more dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.-ctor):

```
public SignInManager(
    UserManager<TUser> userManager,
    IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
    IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser> claimsFactory,
    IOptions<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
    ILogger<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>> logger,
    IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes);
```

Comment: I had tried this previously, but the part that gives me problems was mocking the IAuthenticationSchemeProvider. It doesn't seem to be found within the namespace using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe your test project does not have a reference to the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions) package where the interface is located inside.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me against .NET 6.0:

```
public class FakeUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public FakeUserManager()
        : base(
              new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
              new Mock<Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
              new Mock<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
              new IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>[0],
              new IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>[0],
              new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
              new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
              new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
              new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>>().Object)
    { }
}

public class FakeSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
{            
    public FakeSignInManager()
        : base(
              new Mock<FakeUserManager>().Object,
              new HttpContextAccessor(),
              new Mock<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
              new Mock<Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
              new Mock<ILogger<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>>().Object,
              new Mock<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider>().Object,
              new Mock<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserConfirmation<ApplicationUser>>().Object
              )
    { }
}
```

...and then

```
var signInManagerMock = new Mock<FakeSignInManager>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I directly fake `SignInManager<User>` via [FakeIsEasy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FakeItEasy/) in ASP.NET Core 5:

```
var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(Enumerable.Empty<Claim>()));
var signInManager = A.Fake<SignInManager<User>>();
A.CallTo(() => signInManager.IsSignedIn(claimsPrincipal)).Returns(false);
...
A.CallTo(() => _signInManager.SignOutAsync()).MustHaveHappened();
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in .NET 6.0 only after removing "IUserConfirmation" from the SignInManager constructor:

```
 _mockUserManager = new Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(
          new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
          new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
          new Mock<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
          new IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>[0],
          new IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>[0],
          new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
          new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
          new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
          new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>>().Object);

_mockSignInManager = new Mock<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>(
            _mockUserManager.Object, 
            new HttpContextAccessor(), 
            new Mock<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>>().Object, 
            new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
            new Mock<ILogger<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>>().Object, 
            new Mock<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider>().Object
          );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).