# Mocking issue: Can not instantiate proxy of class: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I am trying to create a unit test using Moq which test Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity user manager. I know that Moq is good for mocking interfaces, but UserManager does not have interface.

Here is my code:

```
Mock<UserManager<User>> userManagerMock = new Mock<UserManager<User>>();
// rest of my code ...
```

here is the error:

> Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can
> not instantiate proxy of class:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[[WebAPI.Core.Model.User,
> Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
> Could not find a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Can you provide a specific code example? Or you can check this post first, which may help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189741/mocking-a-signinmanager

Comment: It looks like `UserManager<User>` does not have a parameterless constructor. If you want to mock a concrete class, it should have a parameterless constructor. Otherwise, you should mock to an interface of it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can mock classes with `Moq`. You just need to create a new `Mock` with valid constructor parameters.
In your case:

```
var userManagerMock = new Mock<UserManager<User>>(Mock.Of<IUserStore<User>>(), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

When creating new mock for class, Moq uses one of the constructors of the class, in the `UserManager` class, there is a single constructor with 9 parameters:

```
UserManager<TUser>(IUserStore<TUser>, IOptions<IdentityOptions>, IPasswordHasher<TUser>, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TUser>>, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TUser>>, ILookupNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber, IServiceProvider, ILogger<UserManager<TUser>>)
```

The only parameter that is mandatory is the first one, all the others you can pass `null` value.

Now you can setup any virtual method or property.

**Full example:**

```
[TestMethod]
public void MockUserManager()
{
    // Arrange
    var userManagerMock = new Mock<UserManager<User>>(Mock.Of<IUserStore<User>>(), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    userManagerMock.Setup(x => x.CheckPasswordAsync(It.IsAny<User>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(true);

    // Act
    var res = userManagerMock.Object.CheckPasswordAsync(new User(), "123456").Result;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(res);
}

public class User
{
}
```

Comment: That helped me for mocking Mock<EntityEntry<MyClass>>(null);